# Create arrow class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an arrow class that takes two Points.  This is what I have:

```
struct Arrow : Lines {              // an Arrow is a Line that has an arrow at the end
    Arrow(Point p1, Point p2)       // construct an Arrow from two points
        :p1(p1), p2(p2) {}
    void draw_lines() const;

    Point p1;
    Point p2;
};
```

This is what I have of the draw_lines() const function:

```
void Arrow::draw_lines() const
{
    Lines arrow;
    arrow.add(p1, p2);
    arrow.draw_lines();

}
```

It works by typing `Arrow a(Point(x,y), Point(x1,y1));`.  It is then supposed to calculate the arrow using (x,y), which becomes p1, and (x1,y1), which becomes p2, as guides to the direction and (x1,y1) as the arrow base point.  I would like the arrow to look like this, only solid: --->.  How can I calculate the angle that the arrow points?  The lines of the arrow head need to be as two x,y coordinates, such as (p2.x, p2.y, (x coordinate of back point of arrow relative to p2), (y coordinate of back point of arrow relative to p2).  The .x and .y notation returns the x and y coordinates of Point p.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Angle between the arrow and what?  `atan2` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2) will probably be helpful.

Comment: You'll need to calculate the slope of the line x,y - x1,y1, then calculate the endpoints of the arrowhead using point-slope-distance originating from the end of the arrow shaft, using some pre-defined(or possibly calulated from the length of the shaft) distance as the size of the arrowhead.

Comment: @aschpler:  Thank you, I thought it required something about atan().  I will look into this.  I meant the angle between the line itself and the line of the arrow head.

Comment: An equivalent way to look at the problem is converting a vector (x1 - x, y1 - y) in rectangular coordinates into polar coordinates...

Comment: @twalberg How could I do this?  I've been trying to work with polar coordinates, but I do not know how to use them on the screen.  Ideally, I would like to enter a const int to be added or subtracted to the angle of the slope to create the angle of the arrowhead lines, and another for the length, and it takes care of the nitty gritty point coordinates itself.

Comment: This Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) should give you a good place to start

Comment: Thank you, @twalberg.  I know how to use polar coordinates, but the graphics library gives me two options for drawing lines:  fl_line(int x, int y, int x1, int y1) to draw a line from (x,y) to (x1,y1), and fl_line(int x, int y, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) to draw a line from (x,y) to (x1,y1), then another from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2).  I am using FLTK, because that is what Bjarne Stroustrup told me to use.  How can I get it to work with polar coordinates?

Comment: If the library doesn't have routines to do the conversions between cartesian and polar coordinates, you'll have to write the conversions yourself. sqrt(x*x+y*y) and atan2(y,x) go one direction, and r*cos(theta) and r*sin(theta) to go the other direction...

Comment: Thanks to all your help, I finally have this solved.  I cannot post the final answer for two more hours because I only have one point, but I will do so then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what it looks like using `atan2`.

```
const double pi = 3.1415926535897931;
const int r = 5;
const double join_angle = pi / 6.0; // 30 degrees
const double stem_angle = atan2(p2.y-p1.y, p2.x-p1.x);

Lines arrow;
arrow.add(p1, p2);
arrow.add(p2, Point(p2.x - r*cos(stem_angle+join_angle), p2.y - r*sin(stem_angle+join_angle)));
arrow.add(p2, Point(p2.x - r*cos(stem_angle-join_angle), p2.y - r*sin(stem_angle-join_angle)));
```

This is exactly the approach you described in your comment:

> Ideally, I would like to enter a const int to be added or subtracted to the angle of the slope to create the angle of the arrowhead lines, and another for the length, and it takes care of the nitty gritty point coordinates itself.

Except that `double` is much better than `int` for storing the `join_angle` in radians.

Comment: Thank you.  That is so much neater and cleaner.  I never used atan2() before, so I didn't know how to use it.  I will study your example until I get it.  This will be very helpful for other problems I've been having.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trigonometric functions like atan. Just normalize the vector from p1 to p2 (you need sqrt for that), get the orthogonal vector to that (easy in 2D) and get the missing two points by adding multiples (factors determine length and width of the arrow head) of these two unit vectors to the end point.